# Saving an int and displaying it in an alertdialouge using sharedpreferences Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Hi so im trying to make a game and I want the highscore to be save. From what Ive read its best to used sharedpreference. Here is my code:

I declare the ints here

```
 public int score;
public int highScore;
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "HighScore";
```

Then Ive called it in the on create.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putInt("Hscore", highScore);
    editor.commit();

}
```

and now i want to display the highscore in an alertdialouge

```
  AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlert.setTitle("You have lost");
        myAlert.setMessage("Your score was :" + score + "\n" + "Your Highscore is :" + \\read highscore and display here)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        score=0;
                        TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
                        String points = String.valueOf(score);
                        myScore.setText(points);
                    }
                })
                .create();
```

Thank you for your help

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public int score;
public int highScore = 10;
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "HighScore"; // This is shared preference name


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

   /*SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
    editor.putInt("HighScore", highScore);
    editor.apply(); // Use editor.apply() for saving in background*/

    SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
    int currentscore;
    currentscore = 10;
    highScore = data.getInt("Hscore", 0); // lets say highscore = 100
    if(highScore>currentscore)
    {
        // This will store the new high score in the sharedpreferences.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
        editor.putInt("Hscore", highScore);
        editor.commit(); // Use editor.apply() for saving in background
        // after this highscore will be 100
    }

}

public void generateH(View v){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
    TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coinResult);

           if (number == 1){
        myText.setText("HEADS");
        TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        score = score+1;
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);


    }

    else{
        myText.setText("TAILS");



        AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlert.setTitle("You have lost");
        myAlert.setMessage("Your score was :" + score + "\n" + "Your Highscore is: " +  data.getInt("Hscore", 0) )
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();
        score = 0;
        TextView myScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);

        myAlert.show();
    }

}
public void generateT(View v){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
    TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coinResult);

    if(score > highScore){
        highScore = score;
    }


    if (number == 1){
        myText.setText("HEADS");



        AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlert.setTitle("You have lost");
        myAlert.setMessage("Your score was :" + score + "\n" + "Your Highscore is :" + data.getInt("Hscore", 0))
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();

        score = 0;
        TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);
        myAlert.show();

    }

    else{
        myText.setText("TAILS");
        TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        score = score+1;
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);
    }

}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: You can use the same SharedPreferences object to retrieve the specific value. Take a look at getInt() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process is simple.
Steps to use Sharedpreferences :

Step 1 : You need to Create a shared preference variable to save high Score.

Step 2 : Need to save the current high score to the shared preference variable.

Step 3 : Retrieve the high score when you needed.

Try the below code :

```
public int score;
public int highScore;
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "HighScore"; // This is shared preference name


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**// Initializing the shared preference**

```
data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
```

**// This is where you insert/store the Highscore value in the shared preference**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit(); 
editor.putInt("Hscore", highScore);
editor.commit(); // Use editor.apply() for saving in background

} // on create ends
```

**Getting the value from the Sharedpreferences - Syntax**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
int value = data.getInt("KEY VALUE", "DEFAULT VALUE"); // If there is no shared preference defined for the given key value default value is returned.
```

**Displaying the High Score in Alert dialog**

```
SharedPreferences data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlert.setTitle("You have lost");
    myAlert.setMessage("Your score was :" + score + "\n" + "Your Highscore is :" + data.getInt("Hscore", 0)) // refer syntax
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    score=0;
                    TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
                    String points = String.valueOf(score);
                    myScore.setText(points);
                }
            })
            .create();
```

**Resources :**

[Android Developer Page](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

[Tutorial 1](http://androidexample.com/Android_SharedPreferences_Basics/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=126&aaid=146)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)

Refer the above links..!! which will be much helpful.

This will help you ..!! try it...

**Updated Answer**

```
public void generateH(View v){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
    TextView myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coinResult);

    if (number == 1){
        myText.setText("HEADS");
        TextView myScore = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        score = score+1;
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);
        if(highScore>points)
        {
            // This will store the new high score in the sharedpreferences.
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("Hscore", highScore);
            editor.commit(); // Use editor.apply() for saving in background
            // after this highscore will be 100
        }else
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("Hscore", points);
            editor.commit();
        }

    }

    else{
        myText.setText("TAILS");
        score = 0;
        TextView myScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreTxt);
        String points = String.valueOf(score);
        myScore.setText(points);
        if(highScore>points)
        {
            // This will store the new high score in the sharedpreferences.
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("Hscore", highScore);
            editor.commit(); // Use editor.apply() for saving in background
            // after this highscore will be 100
        }else
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("Hscore", points);
            editor.commit();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        myAlert.setTitle("You have lost");
        myAlert.setMessage("Your score was :" + score + "\n" + "Your Highscore is: " +  data.getInt("Hscore", 0) )
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .create();

        myAlert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: i get an error saying sharedPreferences cannot be applied to given types; required: string,int found: string, string.     Im not sure whats happened here?

Comment: at which line you are getting this error?  or when you are getting this error?

Comment: any point i use this SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
int value = data.getInt("KEY VALUE", "DEFAULT VALUE");  also where is the best place to use that line

Comment: oh.. cool dude, replace "Default value" with any default number like 0. since you are using the int as return type.

Comment: added some useful reference links.. refer them

Comment: Ok so when i use it now I think its geting reading the file but its not saving the data. When it its displayed it comes up with 0

Comment: I'm sorry i dont understand. What should be happening is that the value of highScore should be getting replaced with the value of score if it is higher than highScore. However niether the value of score or highScore are getting saved.

Comment: Do this. make work with the if else condition. check my updated answer

Comment: Now im confused as to where i declare that block of code now. Ive used it to replace the code in the oncreate method however i still get highScore displaying as 0 in my alertdialog

Comment: post your entire activity. i'm not getting you.

Comment: you need to store highscore after getting the current score. check the updated answer. I have done it for only one function.

Comment: So it seems to work now the only issue is that once a new score is made it resets the highscore to that. Also where you have declared if(highscore > points) i changed points to score as points is a string and was causing errors

Comment: Thats fixed now. But when i close the app the data is reset. is there anyway the data can be saved for when the app is closed

Comment: Data will not be resetted in the shared preference.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening then cause when I close the app and reopen the high score still there when I get an alert. However on the next alert it will replace the highscore with the score I just got even if it is lower

Comment: you need to check the condition before you insert it into the shared preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a separate class as:

```
public class ScoreSharedPreference {

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "SCORE_PREFS_";
    private static final String CURRENT_SCORE = "CURRENT_SCORE";
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    public ScoreSharedPreference(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }

    public void saveScore(int score) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(CURRENT_SCORE, score);
        editor.commit();
    }



    public int getScore() {
       return prefs.getInt(CURRENT_SCORE, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can save and get value by calling it simply.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this but do i call the getScore() class so it displays the current highscore in the alertdialoge

Comment: You have to create object for this class. And then call saveScore(yourScore) for saving score. And then call getScore() to get the score.

Comment: So I tried calling saveScore(yourScore) into a if statement:
if(score > yourScore){ 
score = yourScore;
saveScore(YourScore);
};

but it gives me an error. I not good at this saving data so I'm having a lot of trouble with it.

I also delcared yourScore as a public int

Answer (score 0):

```
data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
if(data!=null){
 int previous_highscore = data.getInt("Hscore");
}
```